How to use NVIDIA graphic card in Kubuntu?
I am using Kubuntu 22.04.
I checked the system info :

As you can see, it is not using NVIDIA graphics.
I have NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1650.
So, how can I use the NVIDIA ?
Note: I am using "Asus tuf f15" laptop.
